# Microsoft GRAPH API to get total number of mails in my inbox

Tags: python, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I am writing to script to check my mail and download the attachments. What I am trying to do is to check my Total inbox mail count every 5mins and find if there is a new mail and download its attachments.
I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?tabs=aad) python tutorial.
Below is my function to get the total number of mails in my inbox

```
def get_all_msg(self):
    endpoint = '/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages'
    request_url = f'{endpoint}?$count=true'

    inbox_response = self.user_client.get(request_url)
    return inbox_response.json()['@odata.count']
```

This returns 1520 but the total number of mails in my inbox is around 250
But if there is a new mail the function returns 1521 (gets incremented by 1 expected)

Not sure if this is the correct approach

Any input is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to use [message delta](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get a set of messages that have been added, deleted, or updated in a specified folder. It's better approach then check mails count.

```
GET /me/mailFolders/inbox/messages/delta
GET /me/mailfolders/inbox/messages/delta?changeType=created
```

It will return a message collection.